# DIVs com float right sem a sua posição invertidada

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber como garantir que duas `DIV`, ambas com `float:right`, não inverterem a posição entre si, por exemplo:

```
<div id="divMaster">

    <div class="pull-right" id="Div1">    
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right" id="Div2">
    </div>

</div>
```

Sendo que a `#Div1` continue a esquerda da `#Div2`.

**Obs:**
`pull-right` é uma classe do Twitter Bootstrap, mas é a mesma coisa que o `float:right;`.

Comment: Podes sempre trocar a ordem das div's e já fica direito como queres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer uso de uma *wrapper*:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/9LQhg/)

```html
<div id="divMaster">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <div class="pull-left" id="Div1"></div>
      <div class="pull-left" id="Div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vlw, funcionou aqui @Zuul!